# abnormal behaviour of netlogo in calling turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I have been facing weird problem in my netlogo program. When i use ask turtles command, some times it call one or two turtles more than once. for instance if I have 3 turtles and their who's are 0 1 2. if I use ask turtles in the program, some times it call one of the turtles more than once. For example it might called turtle with who 0 twice. It happens some times, means not in every tick. Any suggestion, why it is causing this problem and how to fix this issue?

Comment: can we please see the code? how do you know that it is asking a turtle more than once?

Comment: I recommend the following approach to your question:  assume you are wrong.  Asking any agentset (including turtles) will ask each one *once*.  Now that you have settled that, you can begin to look for what aspect of your code is causing the apparently anomalous behavior.

Comment: @JenB the program was starting produce undesirable output. when i debugged the program (I started printing who of turtles), i found that in few ticks ask turtles command call some turtles more than once. In my programe turtles categorizes into two breeds. I checked on both breeds and found the same problem. I already make sure that i am not calling any command or method more than once.

Comment: I am reasonably confident that the problem is in your code, not the ask. Try putting the print statement as the first thing in the command block of the ask. You will probably find that somewhere in the command block you switch turtles (eg by asking for the property of a neighbour, or having a second ask nested within the first ask) and that's what is causing your duplication.